# How to conditionally autowire a configuration class within service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

Currently, I have a service class within which I am trying to constructor auto wire Configuration class. However, I would expect my service class to be generic and work for any Configuration class with similar properties.
Is there a way I can conditionally auto wire configuration class in the service class based on parameter. I don't want any if-else condition.
Below is my sample code snippet

```
    @Service
    public ServiceClass {
    private COnfigurationClass configurationClass

    public ServiceClass(COnfigurationClass configurationClass) {
       this.configurationClass = configurationClass
    }

    //Some method that makes use of configuration class

    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="abc")
    public class COnfigurationClass {
      enter code here
    }
```

I want my ServiceClass to auto wire new ConfigurationClass with prefix="xyz" based on parameter i pass while initializing ServiceClass

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html . @Profile helps you create a bean based on the profile active.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to solve this. I created a base Class which was extended by multiple Configuration class which all had the same config properties.

Now I autowire all config classes as List

Below is my example

```
@Component
public class BaseConfig {

}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="abc")
public class ConfigABC extends BaseConfig {

}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="xyz)
public class ConfigXYZ extends BaseConfig {

}



@Service
public SomeService {

@Autwire
List<BaseConfig> baseConfig; //baseConfig contains the list of all BaseConfig classes

baseConfig.checkForSomeProperty() //Determine which config property to use

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

so a simple solution would be to add a annotation of
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "bean.enabled")
on the method where your bean is being created (configurationClass bean)

and while autowiring it in your service class use
 @Autowired(required=false)
though you will have to do null check later while using

refer to the similar question which could help,
[How to Autowire conditionally in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656119/how-to-autowire-conditionally-in-spring-boot)