# Need Suggestion to Fix Autowire Issue in controller

Tags: java, spring, autowired, beancreationexception

we have a controller which gets called by cron job for healthcheck purpose in our spring application

Because we are in mid of migration process, we are disabling certain spring beans for spring profile p2 which is the new platform,  and only creating them for p1 which is old profile

currently if we build our application in the new platform, we receive the following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'some.name.of.controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private [ bean that is disabled in p2 ] bean that is disabled in p2 ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ bean that is disabled in p2 ] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

```
@Controller("some.name.of.controller")
@RequestMapping("/somePath")
public class someHealthCheckController {


// the SecretObject will not be available for spring profile "p2" which only gets created in profile "p1"
@Autowired
private SecretObject secretObject
```

I have tried extract this autowired line into a new Java class, and having the controller create an instance of the class and invoke that method, but it didn't work.

Looking for suggestions on fixing this issue, thanks !

Comment: Did you check component scan list if the controller package is added into packages to be scanned ?

Comment: @SagarGandhi Not sure I get your point here, the controller stills gets called properly by the cron. The issue resides with the autowired line, it is requiring a bean that doesn't exist for profile p2

Comment: I mean the bean for which Spring is saying no bean found. Is that bean created by the spring ?  Spring creates beans based on package list that you provide (looks for @ComponentScan on configuration or in xml.  If package is not specified (or parent package) then spring won't create a bean.

Comment: @SagarGandhi Yea, it is already included in the component scan, double checked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Autowire conditionally in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656119/how-to-autowire-conditionally-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SecretObject does not exists in your `p2` profile, the dependency is optional, so you must annotate it with `@Autowired(required=false)` and check if secretObject is null (`p2` profile) or not (`p1` profile) before using it. Default value of `required` is `true` for `@Autowired`.

```
@Controller("some.name.of.controller")
@RequestMapping("/somePath")
public class someHealthCheckController {


// the SecretObject will not be available (null) for spring profile "p2" which only gets created in profile "p1"
@Autowired(required=false)
private SecretObject secretObject
```